# Target anchor tag within an anchor with CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, inspect

How can I target with css the anchor tag named `#individualProfile` that is a child of another `a href`?

I have this from inspected element, where the tag is appended using `append()`

[image: image from expect element]

Comment: Anchors within anchors is invalid HTML. If it's an anchor that has no href (as in your example) **don't use an anchor**.

Comment: @Paulie_D this is JQM special markup.

Comment: @OmarI have no idea what that is...but it's still invalid HTML.

Comment: Post your markup pls not a snapshot.

Comment: @Paulie_D Jquery mobile framework. It has its own markup, events, etc.

Comment: Doesn't make it any less invalid.

Comment: Hi guys, I just wanted to say that the first anchor is the consequence of a clone function, where I have appended the link. `$(this).clone().appendTo('#myPost').append('<a href="#individualProfile"></a>');`

Comment: Why not just give it a class?

Answer (score 4):

As Paulie_D just mention, you shouldn't have an `a` wrapped in another `a`.

Meanwhile, **if you can't change the HTML structure**, you can try this :

```
a[href] > a[href="#individualProfile"]{
   ...
}
```

This targets the first `a` with an `href` attribute, then the `>` select a direct child of it, and then specify the `a` with the wanted `href`.

This should anyway be more specific, as there can be a lot of other `a` with `href` attributes in your page than the one you want to style.

[Here's a reference on MDN of attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for further informations.